# Wordpress site within subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed WP in the "/news"of a website. The idea is that the site owner can update the latest company news in this section.

The site I have created includes a fixed top menu on each page. How, can I put this on the wordpress page? I have a header file that is included on every other page and I also want this fixed the the /news (WP) part of the site.

Comment: You may include the same header file or code from that file into your current wp theme's header.php file in news/wp-content/themes/your-select-theme

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Now how to I get all posts to be displayed on that page?

Comment: Great it worked for you. Which page? WP should by default show all posts on your main page. Just make sure wp theme you using have default WP loop code. https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop (I am posting above solution as answer please mark resolved if it solves original question. Thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include any custom PHP code or file on every page of the WordPress pages. You can include that code or file in your current WordPress theme's header.php file.

As you have already header code/file, You may include the same header file or code from that file into your current wp theme's header.php file in news/wp-content/themes/your-select-theme

You may need to fix the paths etc but it is the way we can include on every wp page any common code in the header.